# Jekyll static site generation on a subsite?

Tags: github, web, markdown, jekyll

Is it possible to have Jekyll on a single subsection of my website hosted on GitHub? i.e. is it possible to have "example.github.io" be a regular site and "example.github.io/blog" be statically generated by Jekyll?

I believe it's possible to do this by creating another GitHub repo called "blog" and having that repo managed by Jekyll. I'm wondering if it can all be done in one main "example.github.io" repo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You just have to use the `Exclude` setting in your `_config.yml` to tell Jekyll which files and/or folders it should ignore. Similarly, you can also use the `Include` setting to specifically include files and/or folders.

> Configuration Settings / Global Configuration
>
> https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#global-configuration

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to just have a "blog" directory within my site, and initialize just that blog directory as a Jekyll site? e.g. by navigating to "blog" and running "Jekyll new"

Comment: This can be done setting the `url` parameter as your domain and `baseurl: "/blog"` in your `_config.yml`. For more explanation, I'd check out the link Caio provided above.